# How to get the Windows install date of virtual machines in a cluster?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I have about 127 virtual machines in a Hyper-V cluster with 6 nodes.  I'm trying to get a nice list of the Windows install dates for each VM using PowerShell.  I have this so far, but it only returns the install dates of the nodes.

```
$clusterNodes = Get-ClusterNode

ForEach($item in $clusterNodes) {
  gcim Win32_OperatingSystem | select Name, InstallDate
}
```

How do I extend this so that it grabs the info from the VMs instead of the nodes themselves?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Hyper-V host (much less a cluster) at hand, but I'd try the following:

- enumerate the cluster nodes
- enumerate the VMs on each node
- get the network adapter for each VM
- expand the IP address(es) for each adapter and select one
- run the `Get-WmiObject` query against each selected IP address

Something like this (untested):

```
Get-ClusterNode -Cluster clustername | ForEach-Object {
  Get-VM -Computer $_.Name | Get-VMNetworkAdapter |
    Select-Object -Expand IPAddresses |
    Where-Object { $_ -like '192.168.23.*' } |
    ForEach-Object {
      Get-WmiObject -Computer $_ -Class Win32_OperatingSystem |
        Select-Object __SERVER, Name,
          @{n='InstallDate';e={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.InstallDate)}}
    }
}
```

The calculated property is to convert WMI date strings to actual `DateTime` values.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? (Also you don't have to loop for gcim since it can run in parallel)

```
$VMnames = (Get-ClusterNode -Cluster clustername | %{Get-VM -server $_.name}).computername
gcim Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $VMnames | select Name, InstallDate
```

Comment: Does the `ComputerName` property hold the actual hostname of the system in the VM? If it's just an alias property for `Name` (which I suspect) you may not want to use it, since the VM name can be different from the actual hostname.

Comment: Judging from this [image](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/567318) found in [this TechNet post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/890c0a49-28f6-4475-a928-7aa345de021d/where-are-docs-for-virtualmachine-object?forum=winserverpowershell), name and computername are separate properties where name is the name of the vm and computername is the hostname of where that VM is located. But I do see the issue then, as it will ask the query the VM host several times rather than the individual VMs, I believe name may need to be used rather than computername

Comment: I don't see -server as a parameter, it fails on that.

Comment: @Pickle Use `-Computer` instead of `-Server`.

Comment: Hmm, nope still running into weird errors.  I'm going to have to do this manually.